# ionic framework floating bubble icon notification

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, floating

Is it possible to implement floating bubble icon notification over the screen like Facebook in ionic?

I've done it, with an external app that catch my ionic app notification.
But i want do it with my app.

Comment: This quesitons is too broad, assuming you want more than a simple yes it possible to implement

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Did you mean **Toast** or **Push Notification**? Both link given -
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push